# Is there a flag to silence docker when an empty list is provided

Tags: bash, docker

Such a feature is useful when running multiple docker commands in one that follow this pattern:

```
docker do_smth $(docker query_smth)
```

For example:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

or

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

or

```
docker network rm $(docker inspect ... --format ...)
```

If the inner docker command returns an empty list, the outer command will fail because and will display the help.

```
"docker stop" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker stop --help'.

Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...] [flags]

Stop one or more running containers
```

Is there a way to silence docker or make docker not complain on empty lists? Something like: "Kill everybody. If there is no one, job done."

This would be similar to `mkdir -p exiting_directory` vs `mkdir exiting_directory` where the former will not complain if the directories exist.

Answer (score 6):

For scripting where the result may be empty, I prefer to use `xargs --no-run-if-empty`:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm
```